# Python type error while embedding

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, com, python-embedding

I am trying to run following python code from c++(embedding python).

```
import sys
import os
import time
import win32com.client
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
import re
import pythoncom
import thread
os.popen('adb devices')
CANalyzer = None
measurement = None

def can_start(config_path):

    global CANalyzer,measurement
    CANalyzer = win32com.client.Dispatch('CANalyzer.Application')
    CANalyzer.Visible = 1
    measurement = CANalyzer.Measurement
    CANalyzer.Open(config_path)
    measurement.Start()
    com_marshall_stream = pythoncom.CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(pythoncom.IID_IDispatch,CANalyzer)
    return com_marshall_stream
```

When i try to call `can_start` function, i am getting python type error . Error traceback is mentioned below.

```
"type 'exceptions.TypeError'. an integer is required. traceback object at 0x039A198"
```

The function is executing if i directly ran it from the python and also it is executing in my pc, where the code was developed. But later when i transferred to another laptop, i am experiencing this problem.

Comment: The simplest way to debug this would be to print the exception using `PyErr_Print()`.

Comment: ya i am doing that. it is saying "type 'exceptions.TypeError'. an integer is required. traceback object at 0x039A198"